# Definite Integral of Piecewise Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, area

The function

$$
f(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&1 ,\ x \in [0,1)\\
&2 ,\ x \in [1,2]
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

is piecewise continuous. Find and draw the area function $F(x) = \int^x_0 f(t) \ dt$ for $x \in [0,2]$.

---

**My Work**

We know that $F(x) = \int^x_0 f(t) \ dt$ for $x \in [0,2]$ is the area function.

$\therefore F(2) = \int^2_0 f(t) \ dt = \int^1_0 f(t) \ dt + \int^2_1 f(t) \ dt$

$= \int^1_0 1 \ dt + \int^2_1 2 \ dt$

But I get stuck here.

---

In my understanding of integration, I do not see any errors in my reasoning up to this point; but I must have made some error that prevents me from moving forward from here.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain the error in my reasoning, what the correct solution should be and why it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything you wrote so far is correct, but you are just computing $F(2)$. The question is asking you to graph $F$ on $[0,2]$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$, we have
$$F'(x) = f(x)$$
on $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$. Thus $F$ is a piecewise linear function, with slope $1$ on $(0,1)$ and slope $2$ on $(1,2)$. So to graph it, knowing $F(2)$ is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But wouldn't completing the integrals result in $\int^1_0 1 \ dt + \int^2_1 2 \ dt = [t]^1_0 + [2t]^2_1$ (by taking the antiderivatives)? Isn't this incorrect?

Comment: That gives you $F(2) = 3$, which is correct. Remember that the integral of a constant function is just the constant times the length of the interval, i.e.
$$\int_a^b kdt = k(b - a).$$

Comment: You evaluated $[2t]_1^2$ wrong. It should be $2 \cdot 2 - 2 \cdot 1 = 2$.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. My apologies!

Comment: Ethan, could you please weigh in on whether it should actually be $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \int^x_0 1 \ dt$? My textbook states the following: Assume that for some $a < b$ the function $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a,b)$ but not on $[a,b]$. Define the improper integral of $f$ over $[a, b]$ by $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = lim_{t \to b^-} \int^t_a f(x) \ dx$. Isn't this describing the same function that we have in this question?

Comment: Well yes but that's talking about how to define integrals when the funciton is not defined everywhere on the interval you're integrating over. The point is that changing the value of $f$ at one point doesn't affect the value of the integra. In this case, $f$ is defined at $x = 1$ but not continuous. The integral $[0,1]$, however is still defined.

Comment: I see. But since it is discontinuous for the integral $\int_0^1$, if we are breaking up the integrals into 2 separate ones, as we did above, shouldn't it technically be $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \int^x_0 1 \ dt$? In other words, it IS defined over both integrals (the entire area of integration), but when considering the two integrals separately, as we do with$ \int^1_0 f(t) \ dt + \int^2_1 f(t) \ dt$, is it not technically correct to define the first integral as $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \int^x_0 1 \ dt$?

Comment: It's not incorrect. That limit is the integral. The point is you don't have to do that because the integral is already defined.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you very much for the assistance and insight.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you lost the upper bound

$$F(x)=\int_0^xf(u)\ du=\begin{cases}
\int_0^x\ 1\ du&\text{ if } 0\le x< 1\\
\int_0^1 1\ du+\int_1^x\ 2\ du&\text{ if } 0\le x\le2\\
\end{cases}=$$
$$=\begin{cases}
x&\text{ if } 0\le x< 1\\
1+2(x-1)&\text{ if } 1\le x\le2.\\
\end{cases}$$

And here is the diagram:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Ahh, I think I see what I've done: Instead of finding the area function, what I've done is find the area itself (a constant), right?

Comment: @ThePointer: Right : )

Comment: On a related note, since we have $x \in [0, 1)$, shouldn't the first integral be $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \int^x_0 1 \ dt$?

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can $f$ be continuous if $lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = 1$ and $lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = 2$? Isn't this discontinuous by definition?

Comment: @ThePointer: No, the integral is a continuous function of $x$. The result of the integration would be the same if we had the intervals given as $[0,1]$ and $(1,2]$ or even as $[0,1)$ and $(1,2]$. The integral as a function of $x$ is continuous. It' derivative changes at $1$. The weight of the point $1$ is zero is we do Riemann integration.

Comment: @ThePointer: Sorry, the previous comment was wrong.

Comment: My textbook states the following: Assume that for some $a < b$ the function $f$ is defined and continuous on $[a,b)$ but not on $[a,b]$. Define the improper integral of $f$ over $[a, b]$ by $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx = lim_{t \to b^-} \int^t_a f(x) \ dx$. Isn't this describing the same function that we have in this question?

Comment: Thank you for the assistance in understanding this problem. Your post was very insightful.

Comment: @zoli It seems in bad taste to use the same $x$ for the upper bound, the variable of integration, and the variable whose domain defines the piecewise function. Surely "x" can only fulfill at most two of those roles, formally? What is the rigorous way to write your solution?

Comment: I'm also a bit uncertain of the ranges you listed for x. Surely you meant the second range to be 1 to 2, not 0 to 2? (Otherwise the piecewise function has two overlapping domains, and it's outputs don't always agree.)

Comment: I'll edit. Thx.